# Error en Rutas Laravel 5

Tags: php, javascript, html5, laravel-5, mvc

soy nuevo en Laravel, actualmente tengo un problema.
Tengo un proyecto que me pasaron, que se hizo en la version 5.2 de Laravel, actualmente tengo el 5.7. 
Ejecute los comandos:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Verifique que ya conecta a mi BD en Phpmyadmin.
Mi problema es cuando el usuario entra al proyecto, me sale un error en las rutas.
Accedo mediante localhost a mi proyecto:

```
http://localhost:55/ts_proyect/public
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que investigue hubo cambios en la version anterior a 5.3 en el archivo de Routes que se encontraba en App\Http\routes.php

Estas son las rutas:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::resource('/', 'LoginController');
Route::get('/salir', 'LoginController@salir');
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
Route::resource('mantenedor/docente', 'DocenteController');
Route::resource('mantenedor/tesista', 'TesistaController');
Route::resource('proceso/asignacionjurado', 'AsignacionController');
Route::resource('proceso/entregaborrador', 'EntregaBorradorController');
Route::resource('tesisdetjurado', 'TesisdetJuradoController');
Route::resource('tesisdettesista', 'TesisdetTesistaController');
Route::resource('proceso/observacion', 'ObservacionController');


Route::resource('reportes/rasignadojurados', 'ReporteasignadojuradosController');


Route::get('reporteexcel/rreporteAsignacionJurado', 'ExcelController@reporteAsignacionJurado');
```

Ya llevo mas 5 horas tratando de solucionar esto, estaba pensando en pasarlo a la version, pero de todas formas quiero tratar de solucionar este problema. 
Intente creando un hostvirtual y no me funciono.

Comment: Las rutas en tu proyecto estan en routes/web.php?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, al parecer el public es lo que me generaba conflicto en mi proyecto, por ende debía crear un virtual host en xampp.